# tableviewCellが表示されません

Tags: swift, ios, swift5

現在、チャット一覧画面を作成しているのですが、セルが表示されず困っています。。

とても単純なミスだとは思うのですが、ご教授お願いいたします。

[現在のコード]

```
//
//  ChatListVC.swift
//

import UIKit

let screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds

class ChatListVC: UIViewController {
    
    var chatListTableView = UITableView()
    var chatmember = ["a","b","c","d"]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        chatListTableView.delegate = self
        chatListTableView.dataSource = self
        
        self.setup()
    }
    
}


extension ChatListVC: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatListCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatListCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return screensize.height/15
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
    
}


extension ChatListVC{
    
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
        self.view.addSubview(chatListTableView)
    }
    
    private func setup(){
        self.setupTableView()
    }
    
    private func setupTableView(){
        chatListTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screensize.width, height: screensize.height), style: .plain)
        chatListTableView.register(ChatListCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatListCell")
        chatListTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
    
    
}
```

[cellのコード]

```
import UIKit


class ChatListCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let nameLbl = UILabel()
    let talkLbl = UILabel()
    let profileImageView = UIImageView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        self.addSubview(nameLbl)
        self.addSubview(profileImageView)
        self.addSubview(talkLbl)
    }
    
    func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?,forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String){
        
    }
    
    private func setup(){
        nameLbl.backgroundColor = .yellow
        nameLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 20, width: 300, height: 50)
        nameLbl.text = "fnadifiafia"
        nameLbl.textColor = .black
        talkLbl.backgroundColor = .blue
        talkLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 300, height: 50)
        profileImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

    }
    
}
```

Comment: ご提示のコードを、そのままXcodeの新規プロジェクトにコピー＆ペーストしてみたところ、`screensize`が「unresolved identifier」（未解決の識別子）であるというコンパイルエラー（赤色アイコンのエラー）になりました。プロパティ`screensize`の宣言と定義がコピー時に抜けているようなので、補足してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` で `chatListTableView` にデリゲートとデータソースを設定していますが、その後、 `setupTableView` で新しいUITableViewのインスタンスを作って、それが `viewWillLayoutSubviews` で親Viewに追加されています。

つまり、実際に View 上に配置されたテーブルビューはデータソースが無いので何も表示されません。

`viewDidLoad` と `setupTableView` を以下のようにし、`viewWillLayoutSubviews` のオーバーライドを削除したらセルが表示されるでしょう。

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.view.addSubview(chatListTableView)
        self.setupTableView()
    }
```

```
    private func setupTableView(){
        chatListTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        chatListTableView.delegate = self
        chatListTableView.dataSource = self
        chatListTableView.register(ChatListCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatListCell")
        chatListTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(chatListTableView)
    }
```

（ ChatListCell のコードにもいくつか問題がありそうですが、とりあえずTableView側のみを指摘します ）

Comment: delegateとdatasorceの位置がよろしくなかったのですね、ありがとうございます。

Comment: viewWillLayoutSubviews で毎回新しいテーブルビューを作ることも不適切です。viewDidLoadで実施してください

Comment: 丁寧に教えていただき、ありがとうございます